# How does eviction work in a Infinispan replicated cache?

Tags: caching, infinispan

Infinispan supports a type of cache tier called "Replicated" where the content of multiple caches (in different JVMs or even container instances/VMs/servers) are kept (asynchronously) synchronized. My question is how eviction is handled in this case - if a normal local eviction algorithm is used that only looks at one cache it sounds to me like the result would be suboptimal i.e. entries that is not used much in one JVM and therefore are evicted could be the most frequently used one in all the others (that, as I understand it, also will see these entries evicted due to the synchronization between them)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to check out this section of the Infinispan User Guide https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#eviction-and-expiration_configuring-memory-usage

As you mentioned eviction is done per node and removes entries that were deemed to be used the least most recently. (Note that off JVM heap and on heap have slightly different algorithms). Due to this it is possible to have some nodes with and without data if you have run out of entries. This in turn can cause inconsistencies with what each node can see.

If you need to limit memory usage, which is the main point of eviction, all you need to do to keep consistency between all nodes is to have a persistent storage defined, such as file store which is covered in the next section https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#persistence.

Note that expiration differs from eviction in that it is done cluster wide. So if you still want data consistency across all nodes, expiration can be used instead if it is sufficient for your use case.

Comment: Is it correct to summarize this by saying that only inserts and expiration are synchronized/replicated in replicated caches while eviction is performed individually without replication?
In that case what happens when you create an additional instance of a replicated cache - is it initially empty are only NEW inserts replicated to it will start to fill it up or is there some logic that will copy the existing content of the existing caches (and in that case what content will be copied since the various individual caches may, due to evictions if used, be different)?

Comment: Eviction is only performed on node by node basis, it is not replicated to other nodes. When a new node joins, it will request the existing data from the primary owners of each respective set of data.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications @Mudokonman very appreciated!